# How and when is a @ViewScoped bean destroyed in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, destroy, view-scope

The lifecycle of the  `@RequestScoped` and `@SessionScopedBean` *managed beans* are managed by the Servlet container itself since they are basically stored as an attribute of `HttpRequest` and `HttpSession` respectively. How do JSF manage the lifecycle of the `@ViewScopedBean` ? I know it gets created when the view is created and is usable till there is a postback to a different view. But I found out that is not garbage collected immediately after we move from that view.

Comment: Once a managed bean action method returns a valid navigation case outcome, even though it's to the same view, the view scoped managed bean will be garbaged and recreated. Read this http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html and this is where they stored : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9177769/617373

Comment: Well, in reality, you're not supposed to be able to predict gc or have it happen immediately are you? But regarding the viewscoped beans in mojarra, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13097208/1530938

Comment: garbage collection is asynchronous.  when the view scope is "destroyed" it is really just "marked ready to be garbage collected", just like all other java objects.  Note: the marking is really a reference count of 0 (i.e. marked "no longer used").

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It will be destroyed when

- a postback with a non-`null` outcome is been performed,
- or, the number of (logical) views in session has exceeded and the particular view is the first one in LRU chain (in Mojarra, that's configureable by `com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession` and `com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews` context parameters, each with a default value of 15),
- or, the number of active view scopes in session has exceeded (in Mojarra, that's a hardcoded limit of 25), see also [JSF 2.2 Memory Consumption: Why does Mojarra keep the ViewScoped Beans of the last 25 Views in Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959982/jsf-2-2-memory-consumption-why-does-mojarra-keep-the-viewscoped-beans-of-the-la)
- or, the session has expired.

It will thus **not** be destroyed when the page is unloaded as result of  clicking a GET link to another page, or refreshing the page, or closing the browser tab/window. The bean will live as long until one of abovelisted conditions is met. To destroy it during unload anyway, consider using [OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped) instead.

Comment: what you mean by LRU?Least recently used ? and also what do you mean by *logical* views?

Comment: 1) Yes. They're stored in a LRU map, ordered by last usage. The least recently used is the 1st entry. 2) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562469/how-can-i-set-the-view-timeout/12564632#12564632

Comment: @BalusC, are there any solutions to destory viewscoped beans faster ? will ominfaces viewscoped annotation help with that ?

Comment: in icefaces there is one annotation @WindowDisposed.on browser close itself the view will get garbage collected

Comment: Maybe add some info about the js to immediately do it on 'unload' ?

Comment: @BalusC,is something like the following will force destroy for view scope bean : FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().clear();
for example after click submit button which will process request and after that success message should appear to the user

Comment: @Mahmoud: Nope. View scoped beans are stored in session.