# JSF View Scope Issue - enters init then destroy

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a `ViewScoped` class named SettingsBean ant it has a `ManagedProperty` named UserBean which is `SessionScoped` and its default getter/setter methods.

In my settingsBean, my problem is when I click the page it enters `init` function then it enters `destroy` function as soon as it enters init function.

So I encounter with `java.lang.nullpointerexception` when I call a function with commandbutton `actionListener` to use  the list of selected items of a datatable which is lazy.

When I change the scope as SessionBean everything works normally but this problem forces me to use my bean as session scope and I don't want this.

I use `JSF-2.2`.

What may cause this problem?

Comment: It seems that your View has expired... Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265433/how-and-when-is-a-view-scope-bean-destroyed-in-jsf/15391453#15391453
by BalusC?

Comment: I'm not confident in the `ViewScoped` implementation in JSF-2.2. Are you sure that you're importing the right annotations?