# Manually process `unload` event before triggering `preDestroy` method in OmniFaces ViewScoped bean

Tags: jsf, onbeforeunload, omnifaces, view-scope

As a follow up to my question [@PreDestroy method not called when leaving page of bean annotated with OmniFaces "ViewScoped"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74288390/predestroy-method-not-called-when-leaving-page-of-bean-annotated-with-omnifaces) I have one other question:

Is it possible to process the JavaScript `unload` event manually *before* the `@PreDestroy` annotated method in an OmniFaces `ViewScoped` bean and only trigger the later conditionally if the user confirmed the question? I want to keep using the `unload` event to confirm whether the user really wants to leave the current page like this

```
window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return true; } : void 0;
```

and only bubble the event to the bean annotated with the OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` annotation and trigger the `@PreDestroy` annotated method if the user confirmed the initial `Do you really want to leave the page?` question by clicking `Yes`.

Is that possible?